# What is the source of ESD by soldering?

Tags: soldering, esd, soldering-iron-station

I'd like to know that by soldering a circuit board, what causes the potential difference between the soldering iron and the board. Is it just static electricity (like by hands), or is the power source of the soldering station involved somehow?

Comment: Why do you assume that there's a potential difference?

Comment: Do you have a real problem with ESD? as this question here is relevant : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/357812/152903

Comment: @Humpawumpa Afaik. potential difference is needed for current and ESD itself is a short duration current.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't have real problems with it currently, the question is just theoretical. The other question is related ofc.